# Vapor MySQL Timestamps Default Values

Tags: mysql, swift, xcode, vapor

I am trying to create a model that has various timestamps (createdAt, updatedAt, deletedAt), with default values. How can this be achieved? I tried playing around with the `prepare` method, but to no avail. Thank you in advance.

This is my current class:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vapor offers sth like:

```
 static func prepare(on connection: MySQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Database.create(self, on: connection) { builder in
             builder.field(for: \.iq, type: .int, .default(.literal("123456")))
            ...
```

this should work with Dates as well.

Or you could try to set them in a custom init:

```
 required init(id:Int?, adressLine1:String, adressLine2:String?, city:String, state:String, zip:String) {
    self.id = id
    self.adressLine1 = adressLine1
    self.adressLine2 = adressLine2
    self.city:String = city:String
    self.state = state
    self.zip = zip
    self.createdAt = Date() //<---- here
    self.updatedAt = Date() //<---- here 
    self.deletedAt = Date() //<---- here
}
```

or:

```
required init(id:Int?, adressLine1:String, adressLine2:String?, city:String, state:String, zip:String, 
createdAt:Date = Date()/*<--- here*/, updatedAt:Date = Date()/*<--- here*/,deletedAt:Date = Date()/*<--- here*/) {
        self.id = id
        self.adressLine1 = adressLine1
        self.adressLine2 = adressLine2
        self.city:String = city:String
        self.state = state
        self.zip = zip
        self.createdAt = createdAt
        self.updatedAt = updatedAt
        self.deletedAt = deletedAt
    }
```